# Microsoft Video Screensaver Won't Install - Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, screensaver, windows-genuine-advantage

When I try to install Microsoft Video Screensaver, it tells me I need to validate Windows. When I click "Continue," it opens up a link in IE and runs a script to test my Windows XP copy's validity. It then tells me my Windows copy is genuine, and redirects me to a page with MSE and IE available to download.

Meanwhile, the Microsoft Video Screensaver installer stops and says "Installation was interrupted before Microsoft Video Screensaver could be installed. You need to restart the installer."

I have tried multiple ways to get my Windows validated to work with the installer (it IS genuine), but nothing works (WGAPluginInstall, the WIndows Genuine Advantage Plugin for Firefox fails to install with error code 0x80070003).

What do I do?

Comment: Plugin fails with Firefox. What about Internet Explorer?

Comment: I've tried IE and Chrome, and the legitcheck.hta application. They all just redirect me to a page with MSE and IE available for download after telling me my copy of Windows is genuine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `Installation was interrupted` error comes from Windows Installer. You may have to update your system.

You can try to install [Windows Installer v4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483) and then restart your PC. You will also need [DirectX](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35) runtimes and [.NET Framework v1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26).

Try again to install Video Screensaver. If you still get errors, try to [create an install log](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6bead7aa-cdc5-4b3d-af0c-82f246b2a3b8/the-installer-was-interrupted-before-application-could-be-installed?forum=winformssetup):

```
msiexec /i <path to msi file> /l*vx C:\SomeDirectory\SomeFilename.log
```

Comment: I successfully installed the Windows Installer package, but the DirectX runtimes informed me that I was running a newer version, so I didn't need to install. I've created a PasteBin for my log at [link]http://pastebin.com/PVU9eB4N

Comment: @HyperText404 Line 313: `This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1]. Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.`

Comment: I already have .NET 1.1, which conflicts with 1.0 when I try to install it.

Comment: I see `VideoScreensaver.msi is permitted to run at the 'restricted' authorization level` line in your log. Do you run it as Administrator (right click -> run as administrator)?

Comment: When I run it as administrator, it just throws a User Account Restriction error at me.